# How to put IIS 5.x and 6.x working with WebPages (vbhtml and cshtml)

Tags: iis, asp.net

Can't put IIS 5.1 (Windows XP) and IIS 6.0 (Windows 2003) working with the new Microsoft WebPages (vbhtml and cshtml)... I want a seemless integration to create these pages inside sites that also have HTML, CS, XML, ASPnet, etc. Don't want to use the new IIS express... the pages must work from IIS 5.x or 6.x.
After several configurations (googling and other search methods) I've try several solutions but there is always some error when I invoke a .vbhtml or .cshtml from the browser...

Comment: For what it's worth; I've spent a better part of an entire day trying to get MVC3 working in IIS 5.1 with zero success; not without doing some Route hacks.

Answer (score 1):

The IIS config part should be setup like this walkthrough: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/07/08/configuring-iis6-for-webmatrix.aspx.

Then you also need to upload the dependencies.  If you use the deploy using FTP using the WebMatrix tool, then it should copy the dependencies for you.

If you're deploying it manually using FTP (without WebMatrix) or xcopy, then you need to include them manually to.  You can likely find them in c:\program files(x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET.  Drill into the Assemblies folders and copy to the bin folder on the server.  You can upload all of the assemblies to keep it simple, or else dig around a bit to find out which are specifically needed.  It doesn't hurt to upload extras except maybe a bit longer first load.